# Getting Editor:Error while repo upload in git , working on cygwin editor

Tags: git, cygwin, repository

I am getting an error while trying to repo upload

Command ran as follows -

```
git add <merged Files>
git commit -a -m ""
repo sync
**repo upload** - here I got the error
```

Downloaded git from http://git-scm.com/downloads

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/choudhar/Dev/.repo/repo/main.py", line 385, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/choudhar/Dev/.repo/repo/main.py", line 365, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "/home/choudhar/Dev/.repo/repo/main.py", line 137, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/home/choudhar/Dev/.repo/repo/subcmds/upload.py", line 399, in Execute
    self._MultipleBranches(opt, pending, people)
  File "/home/choudhar/Dev/.repo/repo/subcmds/upload.py", line 235, in _MultipleBranches
    script = Editor.EditString("\n".join(script)).split("\n")
  File "/home/choudhar/Dev/.repo/repo/editor.py", line 96, in EditString
    % (str(e), editor, path))
error.EditorError: editor failed, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: vi /tmp/tmp9S5ZRI
```

I just git add , commit -a -m , repo sync and then tried repo sync.
I am very new user to git

Comment: "repo sync"? you tried what? please provide the commands as to what you're trying, as well as how you actually installed git.

Comment: This is not a git error. As you can see from the output, some Python script (`repo`) is failing. You can push the changes to the repository by using the command `git push origin master`. Some additional work might be needed in the project you're working on, refer to their contributor guide or contact the developers at the mailing list.